# Java Enumerated Types: Functionality

Tags: java, enums

Hey, I am a big fan of using Enumerated Types in Java to aid with code readability and restriction of invalid values.  However, I have been told there is much more that can be done in Java with enums than just creating a named group of possible values.

Could someone list the basic functionality that Java's enums allow as well as an example or perhaps a location where I could get more information on that functionality?

Thank you much,
Black Vegetable

EDIT:
As suggested, this question should be asking what differences there are between an enum and a class in Java.  I wasn't aware they were that powerful?  What ARE the differences then?

Comment: I don't think it's really useful to list what it *can* do.  They can do almost anything a class can do.  So maybe listing how they differ from a class would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences between an enum and a normal class are primarily the guarantees given to you by the JVM's handling of enums.

Lets say you have an enum class (MyEnum) with values (VALUE1 and VALUE2). You are guaranteed that the constructor for that enum class will only ever be executed twice in your JVM*, when serializing and deserializing VALUE1 and VALUE2  you are guaranteed to get the same objects every time so that way object equality works (whereas it will not be guaranteed with other classes... (for example `"Foo" == new String("Foo")` could return false).

Additionally every enum class extends `Enum<T extends Enum<T>>` so you can work with these enum types in a generic fasion as needed (learn to love `name()` and `valueOf()`).

*Classloaders are tricky business... yes there's a slight exception here.

Answer (score 4):

Java's `enum` is basically a full-grown class.

**You can:**

- Declare methods and fields
- Implement interfaces

**But you can't:**

- Extend classes (because `enum`s implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum` already and Java only supports single implementation inheritance)
- Have public constructors

**They have:**

- Some compiler-generated methods like `valueOf` and `values`
- Some additional thread-safety guarantees (a single-item enum is the recommended way to implement singletons in Java)

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces though.

Comment: You can't have a public constructor in an enum.

Comment: Also have a look at EnumMap and EnumSet

Answer (score 2):

There is lots to them, among what other guys have already said.

Let me present one more use you can find for them. I use them as archetypes of objects. This way instead of sending a whole object over the network I am just sending an archetype identifier. Below I present an example taken from a simple game I code for fun and practice.

```
public enum SimpleUnits
{
    BROTHERHOOD_ELITE_TROOPER,
    CAPITOL_FREE_MARINE,
    IMPERIAL_BLOOD_BERET;

    public static SimpleUnit getUnit(SimpleUnits unit)
    {
        SimpleUnit result = null;
//      new SimpleUnit(enumeName, hpMax, speed, CC, MW, PW, LD, ST, MV, AC, W, A, COST);
        switch(unit)
        {
            case BROTHERHOOD_ELITE_TROOPER:
                result = new SimpleUnit(BROTHERHOOD_ELITE_TROOPER.name(), 5, 0.15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 3,
                        5, 3, 2, 1, 100, "images/units/eliteTrooper.png");
                break;
            case CAPITOL_FREE_MARINE:
                result = new SimpleUnit(CAPITOL_FREE_MARINE.name(), 5, 0.15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 3,
                        5, 3, 2, 1, 100, "images/units/freeMarine.png");
                break;
            case IMPERIAL_BLOOD_BERET:
                result = new SimpleUnit(IMPERIAL_BLOOD_BERET.name(), 5, 0.15, 12, 12, 12, 12, 3,
                        5, 3, 2, 1, 100, "images/units/bloodBeret.png");
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public SimpleUnit getUnit()
    {
        return SimpleUnits.getUnit(this);
    }

    public static SimpleUnit getUnit(String enumeName)
    {
        return SimpleUnits.valueOf(enumeName).getUnit();
    }
}
```

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: In this example, where are the types of the parameters for the "constructors" defined?  Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @BlackVegetable the `SimpleUnit` is basically a 'proper' class. That is defined in other file. And as it says it describes a unit. The naming I use is such that I give plural name only to enumerations and its name corresponds to a class for which the enumeration serves as archetype collection.

Comment: It took me a moment to catch that.  I like this style.  However, I do have another very related question but I don't think it merits its own page.  How can I include properties (variables) specific to the enums?  That is, I want to treat it like an abstract class and fill in each parameter according to which enum name is used.

Comment: Since enum can have its own constructor you could try some solution using it constructor, instead of my approach. [There is a nice example in Java tutorials with planets, here.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)